# Python Pyglet application not working in Windows Emacs

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, emacs, python-3.3

I cannot get emacs to evaluate my buffer. I put it into python mode and started the interpreter but C-c C-c does not seem to do anything. I also tried C-c C-l to load the file but after selecting the file nothing happens. Typing directly into the python shell does work.

I tried it out in linux and everything worked fine so I know I am using the correct commands and there is no problem with my code.

I am running GNU Emacs 24.2.1 and Python 3.3 on Windows 7. I am new to emacs and I like it so far, but unless I can get the shell working I will need to switch to a different editor.

**Update:** I am trying to run an application developed with the Pyglet library which creates its own window to display graphics in.

**Update #2:** So if I try to evaluate the buffer and then go to the python buffer and stop compilation and then evaluate it again then it works. This is obviously not ideal.

Also maybe related, any errors or exceptions will not show up in the shell unless I go into the shell and hit enter.

Comment: can you start your python interpreter in the console (`cmd`)?

Comment: That key binding would be a very commonly used one in Emacs and may be used for another active minor mode.  Have you tried executing the command by name using `M-x`?

Comment: @gefei I can start the interpreter in the console, and the interpreter is running in the *Python* buffer. I just cannot seem to get it to evaluate what is in my file.py buffer.

Comment: @MattWhipple I have tried executing the command from both M-x and the menu.

Answer (score 0):

here output arrives in a buffer *Python*, which is not displayed by default unfortunately. M-x list-buffers should mention it.

Comment: The *Python* buffer is being displayed. The problem is that nothing appears in it after using either the 'eval buffer' or 'load file' commands.